# Get model for current controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am building a controller concern, and inside it I need a reference to the current controller's related model. So, if I have something like:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  include Concern
end

module Concern
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  def bla
    self.model # ??
  end
end
```

I would like in `bla` to get a reference of the current model, so that when I include `Concern` in `UserController`, I get a `User` reference.

Is this possible in Rails?

Comment: can't you just do `User.new` in `bla`?(Just asking as I'm new to rails)

Comment: I could do that, but this concern will be included in several controllers, so I need a generic way of getting the model.

Comment: That's fair enough. Thanks for explaining though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do this, but only if you have followed Convention over Configuration for naming the controller and model

```
controller_name.classify.constantize
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access use [controller_name](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Base/controller_name/class) to get the name of controller and then use [classify](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-classify) to get class name.

In short:

```
controller_name.classify
```

Comment: And how do I get the actual reference to the model?

Comment: @linkyndy by `constantize` it

Answer (score 1):

You can infer it from the name of the controller, but it's not 100% reliable, and it will only make sense for RESTful controllers.

This means that if you have an `ArticlesController` with the default RESTful routes (`index`, `show`, `new`, ecc), it is safe to assume that the *related* model will be `Article`. Likewise, you can assume that a RESTful `UsersController` will be about the `User` model.

This of course doesn't make sense for non RESTful controller. You could have a `GraphPollingController`, for example, that does not rely on a specific model.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your controller action call like that

```
self.class.name.sub("Controller", "").singularize.constantize
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following method to your concern:

```
def resource
  resource_name = self
    .class
    .name
    .underscore
    .gsub(/_controller$/, '')
    .singularize

  self.instance_variable_get("@#{resource_name}")
end
```

Now you can retrieve your resource through instance var (i.e. `@user`).